# Building nginx with PCRE on Windows fails on link step for nginx.exe

Tags: c++, windows, nginx, pcre, cl

I am trying to compile nginx with PCRE support on Windows.

My build script is written in bash:

```sh
curl -O https://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre/pcre-8.00.zip
unzip -qd pcre-8.00 pcre-8.00.zip
rm -f pcre-8.00.zip
# For brevity, I'm leaving out how openssl is pulled
pushd openssl
    cmd //c 'mklink /j openssl .'
popd
pushd nginx
    auto/configure \
        --without-http_autoindex_module \
        --without-http_charset_module \
        --without-http_empty_gif_module \
        --without-http_rewrite_module \
        --without-http_scgi_module \
        --without-http_uwsgi_module \
        --with-http_ssl_module \
        --with-http_v2_module \
        --with-stream \
        --with-stream_ssl_module \
        --with-stream_ssl_preread_module \
        --with-http_stub_status_module \
        --with-openssl=../openssl \
        --crossbuild=win32 \
        --with-select_module \
        --with-cc=cl \
        --builddir=objs \
        --prefix= \
        --conf-path=conf/nginx.conf \
        --error-log-path=logs/error.log \
        --http-log-path=logs/access.log \
        --pid-path=logs/nginx.pid \
        --sbin-path=nginx.exe \
        --http-client-body-temp-path=temp/client_body_temp \
        --http-proxy-temp-path=temp/proxy_temp \
        --http-fastcgi-temp-path=temp/fastcgi_temp \
        --with-cc-opt=-DFD_SETSIZE=1024 \
        --with-pcre=../pcre-8.00/pcre-8.00 \
        --with-zlib=../zlib
    nmake -f objs/Makefile
popd
```

The `auto/configure` command runs successfully, with this as its output:

```
building for win32
 + using Microsoft Visual C++ compiler
 + cl version: 19.00.24215.1 for x64
checking for win32 specific features
creating objs/Makefile

Configuration summary
  + using PCRE library: ../pcre-8.00/pcre-8.00
  + using OpenSSL library: ../openssl
  + using zlib library: ../zlib

  nginx path prefix: ""
  nginx binary file: "/nginx.exe"
  nginx modules path: "/modules"
  nginx configuration prefix: "/conf"
  nginx configuration file: "/conf/nginx.conf"
  nginx pid file: "/logs/nginx.pid"
  nginx error log file: "/logs/error.log"
  nginx http access log file: "/logs/access.log"
  nginx http client request body temporary files: "temp/client_body_temp"
  nginx http proxy temporary files: "temp/proxy_temp"
  nginx http fastcgi temporary files: "temp/fastcgi_temp"
```

However, the actual build fails with "unresolved external symbol errors" when it attempts to produce `nginx.exe`. Here is the portion of the build output with the errors:

```
nginx.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ngx_regex_init referenced in function main
ngx_http_fastcgi_module.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ngx_regex_compile
ngx_stream_variables.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ngx_regex_compile
ngx_http_core_module.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ngx_regex_compile
ngx_http_variables.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ngx_regex_compile
ngx_http_ssi_filter_module.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ngx_regex_compile
ngx_http_referer_module.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ngx_regex_compile
ngx_http_core_module.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ngx_regex_exec_array referenced in function ngx_http_gzip_ok
ngx_http_referer_module.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ngx_regex_exec_array
objs/nginx.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

To pick one of these unresolved symbols arbitrarily, `ngx_regex_init` is defined in `ngx_regex.c`. Looking at the code in the [`auto` directory of the nginx source code](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/tree/master/auto), I found that `ngx_regex.c` is only added to the source files that are compiled if `$USEPCRE = YES`. Here is the code in particular (and a [link to the source](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/auto/modules#L1272-L1283)):

```sh
if [ $USE_PCRE = YES ]; then
    ngx_module_type=CORE
    ngx_module_name=ngx_regex_module
    ngx_module_incs=
    ngx_module_deps=src/core/ngx_regex.h
    ngx_module_srcs=src/core/ngx_regex.c
    ngx_module_libs=
    ngx_module_link=YES
    ngx_module_order=

    . auto/module
fi
```

Why wouldn't `$USE_PCRE` be `YES`, since I am using the `--with-pcre` flag?

---

To be sure I'm not failing to provide information, here is the full `cl` command (issued by the nmake Makefile) and its output:

```
cl  -Feobjs/nginx.exe
    objs/src/core/nginx.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_log.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_palloc.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_array.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_list.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_hash.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_buf.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_queue.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_output_chain.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_string.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_parse.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_parse_time.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_inet.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_file.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_crc32.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_murmurhash.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_md5.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_sha1.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_rbtree.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_radix_tree.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_slab.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_times.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_shmtx.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_connection.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_cycle.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_spinlock.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_rwlock.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_cpuinfo.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_conf_file.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_module.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_resolver.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_open_file_cache.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_crypt.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_proxy_protocol.obj 
    objs/src/core/ngx_syslog.obj 
    objs/src/event/ngx_event.obj 
    objs/src/event/ngx_event_timer.obj 
    objs/src/event/ngx_event_posted.obj 
    objs/src/event/ngx_event_accept.obj 
    objs/src/event/ngx_event_udp.obj 
    objs/src/event/ngx_event_connect.obj 
    objs/src/event/ngx_event_pipe.obj 
    objs/src/os/win32/ngx_errno.obj 
    objs/src/os/win32/ngx_alloc.obj 
    objs/src/os/win32/ngx_files.obj 
    objs/src/os/win32/ngx_shmem.obj 
    objs/src/os/win32/ngx_time.obj 
    objs/src/os/win32/ngx_process.obj 
    objs/src/os/win32/ngx_thread.obj 
    objs/src/os/win32/ngx_socket.obj 
    objs/src/os/win32/ngx_wsarecv.obj 
    objs/src/os/win32/ngx_wsarecv_chain.obj 
    objs/src/os/win32/ngx_udp_wsarecv.obj 
    objs/src/os/win32/ngx_wsasend.obj 
    objs/src/os/win32/ngx_wsasend_chain.obj 
    objs/src/os/win32/ngx_win32_init.obj 
    objs/src/os/win32/ngx_user.obj 
    objs/src/os/win32/ngx_dlopen.obj 
    objs/src/os/win32/ngx_event_log.obj 
    objs/src/os/win32/ngx_process_cycle.obj 
    objs/src/event/ngx_event_acceptex.obj 
    objs/src/event/modules/ngx_iocp_module.obj 
    objs/src/event/modules/ngx_win32_select_module.obj 
    objs/src/event/modules/ngx_win32_poll_module.obj 
    objs/src/event/ngx_event_openssl.obj 
    objs/src/event/ngx_event_openssl_stapling.obj 
    objs/src/http/ngx_http.obj 
    objs/src/http/ngx_http_core_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/ngx_http_special_response.obj 
    objs/src/http/ngx_http_request.obj 
    objs/src/http/ngx_http_parse.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_log_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/ngx_http_request_body.obj 
    objs/src/http/ngx_http_variables.obj 
    objs/src/http/ngx_http_script.obj 
    objs/src/http/ngx_http_upstream.obj 
    objs/src/http/ngx_http_upstream_round_robin.obj 
    objs/src/http/ngx_http_file_cache.obj 
    objs/src/http/ngx_http_write_filter_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/ngx_http_header_filter_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_chunked_filter_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/v2/ngx_http_v2_filter_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_range_filter_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_gzip_filter_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/ngx_http_postpone_filter_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_ssi_filter_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_userid_filter_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_headers_filter_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/ngx_http_copy_filter_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_not_modified_filter_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/v2/ngx_http_v2.obj 
    objs/src/http/v2/ngx_http_v2_table.obj 
    objs/src/http/v2/ngx_http_v2_encode.obj 
    objs/src/http/v2/ngx_http_v2_huff_decode.obj 
    objs/src/http/v2/ngx_http_v2_huff_encode.obj 
    objs/src/http/v2/ngx_http_v2_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_static_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_index_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_mirror_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_try_files_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_access_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_limit_req_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_geo_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_map_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_split_clients_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_referer_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_ssl_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_proxy_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_grpc_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_memcached_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_browser_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_hash_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_ip_hash_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_least_conn_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_random_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_keepalive_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_zone_module.obj 
    objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_stub_status_module.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_variables.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_script.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_handler.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_log_module.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_upstream.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_round_robin.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_write_filter_module.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_module.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_limit_conn_module.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_access_module.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_geo_module.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_map_module.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_split_clients_module.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_return_module.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_set_module.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_hash_module.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_least_conn_module.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_random_module.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_zone_module.obj 
    objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.obj 
    objs/ngx_modules.obj 
    kernel32.lib user32.lib advapi32.lib ws2_32.lib ../pcre-8.00/pcre-8.00/pcre.lib ../openssl/openssl/lib/ssleay32.lib ../openssl/openssl/lib/libeay32.lib gdi32.lib crypt32.lib ../zlib/zlib.lib 
    objs/nginx.res -link -verbose:lib -debug objs/ngx_pch.obj
    

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24215.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:objs/nginx.exe 
-verbose:lib 
-debug 
objs/ngx_pch.obj 
objs/src/core/nginx.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_log.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_palloc.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_array.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_list.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_hash.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_buf.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_queue.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_output_chain.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_string.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_parse.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_parse_time.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_inet.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_file.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_crc32.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_murmurhash.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_md5.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_sha1.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_rbtree.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_radix_tree.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_slab.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_times.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_shmtx.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_connection.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_cycle.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_spinlock.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_rwlock.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_cpuinfo.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_conf_file.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_module.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_resolver.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_open_file_cache.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_crypt.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_proxy_protocol.obj 
objs/src/core/ngx_syslog.obj 
objs/src/event/ngx_event.obj 
objs/src/event/ngx_event_timer.obj 
objs/src/event/ngx_event_posted.obj 
objs/src/event/ngx_event_accept.obj 
objs/src/event/ngx_event_udp.obj 
objs/src/event/ngx_event_connect.obj 
objs/src/event/ngx_event_pipe.obj 
objs/src/os/win32/ngx_errno.obj 
objs/src/os/win32/ngx_alloc.obj 
objs/src/os/win32/ngx_files.obj 
objs/src/os/win32/ngx_shmem.obj 
objs/src/os/win32/ngx_time.obj 
objs/src/os/win32/ngx_process.obj 
objs/src/os/win32/ngx_thread.obj 
objs/src/os/win32/ngx_socket.obj 
objs/src/os/win32/ngx_wsarecv.obj 
objs/src/os/win32/ngx_wsarecv_chain.obj 
objs/src/os/win32/ngx_udp_wsarecv.obj 
objs/src/os/win32/ngx_wsasend.obj 
objs/src/os/win32/ngx_wsasend_chain.obj 
objs/src/os/win32/ngx_win32_init.obj 
objs/src/os/win32/ngx_user.obj 
objs/src/os/win32/ngx_dlopen.obj 
objs/src/os/win32/ngx_event_log.obj 
objs/src/os/win32/ngx_process_cycle.obj 
objs/src/event/ngx_event_acceptex.obj 
objs/src/event/modules/ngx_iocp_module.obj 
objs/src/event/modules/ngx_win32_select_module.obj 
objs/src/event/modules/ngx_win32_poll_module.obj 
objs/src/event/ngx_event_openssl.obj 
objs/src/event/ngx_event_openssl_stapling.obj 
objs/src/http/ngx_http.obj 
objs/src/http/ngx_http_core_module.obj 
objs/src/http/ngx_http_special_response.obj 
objs/src/http/ngx_http_request.obj 
objs/src/http/ngx_http_parse.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_log_module.obj 
objs/src/http/ngx_http_request_body.obj 
objs/src/http/ngx_http_variables.obj 
objs/src/http/ngx_http_script.obj 
objs/src/http/ngx_http_upstream.obj 
objs/src/http/ngx_http_upstream_round_robin.obj 
objs/src/http/ngx_http_file_cache.obj 
objs/src/http/ngx_http_write_filter_module.obj 
objs/src/http/ngx_http_header_filter_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_chunked_filter_module.obj 
objs/src/http/v2/ngx_http_v2_filter_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_range_filter_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_gzip_filter_module.obj 
objs/src/http/ngx_http_postpone_filter_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_ssi_filter_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_userid_filter_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_headers_filter_module.obj 
objs/src/http/ngx_http_copy_filter_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_not_modified_filter_module.obj 
objs/src/http/v2/ngx_http_v2.obj 
objs/src/http/v2/ngx_http_v2_table.obj 
objs/src/http/v2/ngx_http_v2_encode.obj 
objs/src/http/v2/ngx_http_v2_huff_decode.obj 
objs/src/http/v2/ngx_http_v2_huff_encode.obj 
objs/src/http/v2/ngx_http_v2_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_static_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_index_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_mirror_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_try_files_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_access_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_limit_req_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_geo_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_map_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_split_clients_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_referer_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_ssl_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_proxy_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_grpc_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_memcached_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_browser_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_hash_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_ip_hash_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_least_conn_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_random_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_keepalive_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_zone_module.obj 
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_stub_status_module.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_variables.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_script.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_handler.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_log_module.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_upstream.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_round_robin.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_write_filter_module.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_module.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_limit_conn_module.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_access_module.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_geo_module.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_map_module.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_split_clients_module.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_return_module.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_set_module.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_hash_module.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_least_conn_module.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_random_module.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_zone_module.obj 
objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.obj 
objs/ngx_modules.obj 
kernel32.lib 
user32.lib 
advapi32.lib 
ws2_32.lib 
../pcre-8.00/pcre-8.00/pcre.lib 
../openssl/openssl/lib/ssleay32.lib 
../openssl/openssl/lib/libeay32.lib 
gdi32.lib 
crypt32.lib 
../zlib/zlib.lib 
objs/nginx.res 

Searching libraries
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\kernel32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\user32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\advapi32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\ws2_32.lib:
    Searching ../pcre-8.00/pcre-8.00/pcre.lib:
    Searching ../openssl/openssl/lib/ssleay32.lib:
    Searching ../openssl/openssl/lib/libeay32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\gdi32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\crypt32.lib:
    Searching ../zlib/zlib.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\LIBCMT.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\OLDNAMES.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\libvcruntime.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.14393.0\ucrt\x64\libucrt.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\uuid.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\kernel32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\user32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\advapi32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\ws2_32.lib:
    Searching ../pcre-8.00/pcre-8.00/pcre.lib:
    Searching ../openssl/openssl/lib/ssleay32.lib:
    Searching ../openssl/openssl/lib/libeay32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\gdi32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\crypt32.lib:
    Searching ../zlib/zlib.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\LIBCMT.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\OLDNAMES.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\libvcruntime.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.14393.0\ucrt\x64\libucrt.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\uuid.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\kernel32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\user32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\advapi32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\ws2_32.lib:
    Searching ../pcre-8.00/pcre-8.00/pcre.lib:
    Searching ../openssl/openssl/lib/ssleay32.lib:
    Searching ../openssl/openssl/lib/libeay32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\gdi32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\crypt32.lib:
    Searching ../zlib/zlib.lib:

Finished searching libraries

Searching libraries
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\kernel32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\user32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\advapi32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\ws2_32.lib:
    Searching ../pcre-8.00/pcre-8.00/pcre.lib:
    Searching ../openssl/openssl/lib/ssleay32.lib:
    Searching ../openssl/openssl/lib/libeay32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\gdi32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\crypt32.lib:
    Searching ../zlib/zlib.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\LIBCMT.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\OLDNAMES.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\libvcruntime.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.14393.0\ucrt\x64\libucrt.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\uuid.lib:

Finished searching libraries
nginx.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ngx_regex_init referenced in function main
ngx_http_fastcgi_module.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ngx_regex_compile
ngx_stream_variables.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ngx_regex_compile
ngx_http_core_module.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ngx_regex_compile
ngx_http_variables.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ngx_regex_compile
ngx_http_ssi_filter_module.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ngx_regex_compile
ngx_http_referer_module.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ngx_regex_compile
ngx_http_core_module.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ngx_regex_exec_array referenced in function ngx_http_gzip_ok
ngx_http_referer_module.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ngx_regex_exec_array
objs/nginx.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `USE_PCRE` is only set to `YES` if the `http_rewrite` module is not disabled and if using PCRE is not disabled. You can see this in the code [here](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/1e8c0d4e0673f50863230eda989867d3012fb349/auto/modules#L659-L670):

```sh
if [ $HTTP_REWRITE = YES -a $USE_PCRE != DISABLED ]; then
    USE_PCRE=YES

    # ...
fi
```

Once I removed the `--without-http_rewrite_module` option from the `auto/configure` command, nginx and PCRE built fine.